# Jquery Autosuggest not working in IE 11 when used in compatability mode

Tags: internet-explorer

I have an autosuggest which is displaying the results properly if used without compatibility mode but when I change the compatibility mode of my browser it dispalyed the result behind the xml which is getting displayed in the page.

**Note**: I am using IE 11 and I have a requirement to display data in xml format using compatibility mode of IE 11.

I am unable to post the snapshot please help :)

Comment: Have you used the browser's error console to see whether there are any problems?

Comment: it is not showing any error in the console its just an css issue as far as I understand but I dont know how to resolve it